# Why wont the plus work properly with this sed command?

Tags: unix, sed

I can't get the `([^/]+)` sed regex to work properly.
Instead of returning all non-forward slash characters, it only returns one.

**Command:**

```
echo '/test/path/file.log' | sed -r 's|^.*([^/]+)/(.*)$|\1.\2|g'
```

**Expected:**

```
path.file.log
```

**Result:**

```
h.file.log
```

**Also Tried this but got the same result:**

```
echo '/test/path/file.log' | sed -r 's|^.*([^/]{1,})/(.*)$|\1.\2|g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `[^/]+`, but with the preceding `.*`. `.*` is greedy, and will consume a maximal amount of input. My usual suggestion would be to use `.*?` to make it non-greedy, but POSIX regexes don't support that syntax.

If there will always be a slash, you could add one to the regex to stop it from consuming too much.

```
$ echo '/test/path/file.log' | sed -r 's|^.*/([^/]+)/(.*)$|\1.\2|g'
path.file.log
```

Comment: And if there isn't necessarily a preceding slash, you'd want `^(.*/)?([^/]+)` to make that part optional - you will need to increment the backrefs to take account of the extra grouping.

Answer (score 0):

OSes uses different versions of `sed`. Some `sed` versions use basic regexp syntax by default; if you need extended regexp syntax (`+` is one of those features) then you need to switch option with `-E`.